# Tool validation - setting error message

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, python-toolbox, tool-validation

I am writing a tool within Python Toolbox that has two parameters:

```
param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
          name="a",
          displayName="A",
          datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
          parameterType="Required",
          direction="Input")

param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
          name="b",
          displayName="B",
          datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
          parameterType="Required",
          direction="Input")

params = [param0, param1]
```

I can´t figure out which `if` statement I should use in `def updateMessages(self, parameters):`. Here is a step-by-step what´s going wrong when I run the tool:

1. I choose a layer from the TOC as `param0`. My validation code is
   `if not parameters[0].hasBeenValidated:
       ... check e.g. if param0 has some attribute field ...
       ... it turns out that such field doesn´t exist, so...
       parameters[0].setErrorMessage("No field!")`
   The red error icon appears next to its label with the message *"No field!"* - everything is working as expected.
2. But then when I choose the second layer from the TOC as `param1` (it has no validation code) the `param0`´s red icon **disappears** like there is no error with the `param0`! I am sure that the problem is with `if not parameters[0].hasBeenValidated:` as I don´t quite understand how it works. I tested several code variants with `.hasBeenValidated`, `.altered` etc. but with no success.

To be short:

1. I would need the red error icon to be displayed as long as there is an error with the `param0` no matter what I do with other parameters **and**
2. (if possible - not mentioned above) ensure that `param0`´s validation performs **only** when the user changes the value of this parameter.

Could you give me a hint how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `altered` method of the `Parameter` object, your simple validation routine should work fine, e.g.,

```
def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    if  parameters[0].altered:
    #check e.g. if param0 has some attribute field ...
    #... it turns out that such field doesn´t exist, so...
        if not "Sought_Field" in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(parameters[0].value)]:
            parameters[0].setErrorMessage("No such field!")
```